# How can I continue the solution? Find the Kernel of a vector space.

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

We are given the vector space $V=F^3$ where $F$ is a field and we are given $B=\{v_1,v_2,v_3\}$ is a basis in $V$, and $T: V \rightarrow V$ is a linear transformation. We are also given:
 $$[T]_B=\begin{bmatrix} -1 & -1 & -3 \\ -5 & -2 & -6 \\ 2 &1 &3  \end{bmatrix}$$Find $\operatorname{Ker}(T)$.

Here is what I tried: for $v \in V$ with $[v]_B=(a,b,c)$ we get that $v$ is in the kernel if and only if $[T]_B \cdot [v]_B = 0$. A simple calculation shows that the requirment is $a=0, b=-3\alpha,c=\alpha$ for some $\alpha \in F$. So we get $\operatorname{Ker}(T)=\{-3\alpha \cdot v_2+ \alpha \cdot v_3 : \alpha \in F\}$.

This is the most simplified answer I got, but the answer should be $\operatorname{Ker}(T)=\operatorname{Span}\left\{(0,-3,1)\right\}$.

Can someone help me get that answer? I'm not sure how to continue.

Comment: You're done. By definition of span, your answer and the expected answer are just two ways to write the exact same vector space

Answer (score 2):

You got it right. Note that\begin{align}-3\alpha v_2+\alpha v_3&=\alpha(-3v_2+v_3)\\&=\alpha(0,-3,1).\end{align}So,\begin{align}\{-3\alpha v_2+\alpha v_3\,|\,\alpha\in\mathbb{R}\}&=\bigl\{\alpha(0,-3,1)\,|\,\alpha\in\mathbb R\bigr\}\\&=\operatorname{span}\bigl\{(0,-3,1)\bigr\}.\end{align}

Comment: There is a small typo on the RHS of your first line ($v_2$ in place of $v_3$). Nice answer anyway, +1.

Comment: I've edited my answer. Thank you.

Comment: @Jose Carlos Santos thanks, but im still confused.  why does a(-3v2+v3)=a(0,-3,1)? if this was true this would mean -3v2+v3=(0,-3,-1) and i don't think that is true, because if for example v2=(0,0,1) and v3=(1,0,0) it is false that -3v2+v3=(0,-3,-1).

Comment: @Omer Remember that you're working in basis $B=(v_1,v_2,v_3)$. Therefore, $v_1=(1,0,0)$,$v_2=(0,1,0)$ and $v_3=(0,0,1)$

Comment: @F.Carette Why? There is more then one basis to a vector space. If we take $v_1=(1,0,0) , v_2=(0,1,0) , v_3=(1,1,1)$ then B is linearly independent and since dimF^3=3 we get that F^3=spanB. so there are more possible bases. We were not given any details about v1,v2 or v3.

Comment: @Omer $-3v_2+v_3=0\times v_1+(-3)\times v_2+1\times v_3$ and therefore, with respect to the basis $B$, $-3v_2+v_3=(0,-3,1)$.